# Getting Error in using user control(.ascx) on asp.net mvc layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, user-controls

I am integrating Asp.net User control(.ascx) in my Mvc Layout page i.e is master page and i am using razor engine.

**Error**:Error executing child request for handler

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper ascx.
                  Control '1_hdfData' of type 'HiddenField' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

This is my code:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@Html.Partial("~/UserControls/Data.ascx")
```

**Data.ascx**:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Data.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNameSpace.Data" %>
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfData" runat="server" />
                --Rest all other asp.net server side controls---.
```

**Data.ascx.cs**:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Data
                {
                     public partial class Data : ViewUserControl
                     {
                         //Page_Load events and other code
                     }
                }
```

Is it like if i am inheriting User Control(.ascx) from `ViewUserControl` so i cant use asp.net control?

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: just need to add form tag in usercontrol

Comment: I liked the topic, it's interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Data.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNameSpace.Data" %>
<form runat="server">
             <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfData" runat="server" />
            --Rest all other asp.net server side controls---.
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this worked correclty but i  need to render 2 user control on my layout page so then where do i put this form tag?

Comment: Give different id to all form tag and use it.

Comment: i have put form tag on 2 user control but it is giving error that:A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Comment: Give both form tag to different id.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing one idea, but it's not good practice.

```
@Html.Partial("_ASCX_FILE")

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="SomeAssembly" Namespace="SomeNs" TagName="ASCX_FILE" %>

<ASCX_FILE:SomeControl runat="server" ID="fooControl" />
```

Possibly above solution can sort out your issue.

```
Suggesting again, try using pure MVC flavor. :)
```